# Vue сохранить состояние роутера

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Как можно сохранить состояние Роутера в Vue?

Пример:

Существует Роутер на (/page1)
на этой странице есть Input, в нем я набрал *Какой-то текст*

После этого перешел на Роутер (/page2), page1 удалился.

Далее перешел опять на (/page1), в Input должен быть *Какой-то текст*, который я набрал ранее.

Comment: Вам, похоже, нужен Vuex

Comment: не нужен Vuex человеку, vue-router красивая обертка над <component>, надо использовать <keev-alive> для кэширования экземпляяра компонента https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш `<router-view>` оберните в `<keep-alive>`